# VS2015 - XAML visual editor gone?

Tags: c#, xaml, visual-studio-2015

I've been using VS2015 since its official release with Windows 10 in a corporate setting (I work as a mobile app developer at my workplace, mainly aiming at Xamarin and UWP apps).

I've started to work on a small library to collect and refine all our common controls, tools, converters, whatnot. However, I've ran into a small issue since opening this project - the XAML visual editor is gone. All I get is the XAML editor, without the option of switching between code and visual views.

I have not installed any new extensions, updates, or anything. Restoring to a previous backup point of the system did not help.

Has anyone else ran into this particular issue?

Comment: Check your project is readonly

Comment: Already done so, it CAN be edited - but the option for switching to the Visual designer does not show up. Neither does the right click -> View Designer option work.

Comment: I had this issue on an IoT proj until I updated to the latest version of win10, if you haven't done that yet might give it a go.

Comment: I'm running the latest 1511 Enterprise build, with latest VS2015 and SDKs. I keep everything up to date as it is required by my job :)